# jQuery missing targets in loaded templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a particular route mapped to a particular controller and a view:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/create', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/form/form.html',
      controller: 'TournamentCreateController'
    });
}]);
```

In this `form` page I am including some partials as well:

```
<div ng-include="'partials/form/start.html'"></div>
```

And this `start.html` has an element like:

```
<input id="time" type="text" ng-model="time">
```

When I try activating JavaScript components on that element, it's completely ignoring its target (`#time`). I tried the following:

```
app.controller('TournamentCreateController', function ($scope, $rootScope, service) {
  $('#time').on('click', function () { alert('Time clicked'); });
}
```

And when the input is being clicked no alert is shown. However if I move that element from `start.html` (the partial) to the parent being that's including it, `form.html`, jQuery is working properly.

What's the issue and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `start.html` DOM is not ready when `$('#time').on('click', function () { alert('Time clicked'); });` is executed.

You can use `ng-click` to do the same.

```
<input id="time" type="text" ng-model="time" ng-click="onTimeClick()">

app.controller('TournamentCreateController', function ($scope, $rootScope, service) {
  $scope.onTimeClick = function () { alert('Time clicked'); });
}
```

Comment: and what if I just want to declare `#time` as a component? I mean, to just bind a function to it so it's a time picker. Or for example, the css framework I am using has built-in directives that automatically do that for you. But the issue remains for the reason you point out (I guess). So how am I supposed to bind it properly?

Comment: @dabadaba in that case you need to create a directive and inside the directive you can manipulate DOM.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a timing issue with event binding. Change your event binding to an element that exists within the parent, and then place '#time' as the second (out of three) parameters for the .on method call.

The .on call would look something like this:

```
$('#<replace_with_id_from_parent_page>').on('click', '#time', function(){ alert('Time clicked'); });
```